# firebase: Could not find Headers implementation, make sure you call FetchProvider.initialize() with an appropriate polyfill error

Tags: node.js, firebase

I'm trying to make node.js code work for firebase authentication,
however got the following error.
I googled but could not get good answer.
I also attached my code below.

Any input is really appreciated.

> [2021-12-18T14:56:02.042Z]  @firebase/auth: Auth (9.6.0): INTERNAL
> ASSERTION FAILED: Could not find Headers implementation, make sure you
> call FetchProvider.initialize() with an appropriate polyfill
> auth/network-request-failed Firebase: Error
> (auth/network-request-failed). FirebaseError: Firebase: Error
> (auth/network-request-failed).

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  appId: "xxx",
  measurementId: "xxx"
};


import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const email = "xxx@gmail.com"
const password = "xxx"

const auth = getAuth();
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    console.log(user)
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
      console.log(errorCode)
      console.log(errorMessage)
  });
```

Comment: A bit late, but any news ? just encountered a relatively close errors :)

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Did you fix this?

Comment: I'm hitting the same error, any updates?